# Filter by row in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
╔════════╦═══════╗
║ ItemID ║ Value ║
╠════════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║ A     ║
║      1 ║ C     ║
║      2 ║ A     ║
║      2 ║ D     ║
║      3 ║ A     ║
║      3 ║ C     ║
╚════════╩═══════╝
```

how can i get the item count only 
the value which are equal to A and C

in this case it should be 2 (item 1 and 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `value` is unique for every `itemId`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
   SELECT ItemID
   FROM tableName
   WHERE value IN ('A', 'C') -- the values you are looking
   GROUP BY ItemID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2       -- the number of values
) a
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb6ae/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Count(Item_Id) from TableName where Value='A' or Value='C'
group by Item_Id having Count(Item_Id)>1
```